# Reference Error:Navigator not defined with nextjs

Tags: next.js

My code is like this:

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

```
import alanBtn from '@alan-ai/alan-sdk-web';

const alanKey = my key;
const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        alanBtn({
            key: alanKey,
            onCommand: ({ command }) => {
                    alert('This code was executed');
            }
        })
    }, []);
    return (
        <div><h1>Alan AI News Application</h1></div>);
}
export default App;
```

But i am getting the error as:
Reference Error:Navigator not defined..
How to fix it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Browser objects like `window` , `navigator` etc should be define in `useEffect` first before use.

```
  const [pageURL, setPageURL] = useState("");
  const [isNativeShare, setNativeShare] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setPageURL(window.location.href);
    if (navigator.share) {
      setNativeShare(true);
    }
  }, []);

// Now, use can use pageURL , isNativeShare in code
```

Comment: Can you please explain the reason.

Comment: Window it's browser object, and the hook will run after it's loaded, that's why it will work

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue with your Next.js code it's just the way you are supposed to call the alan-ai library.

Below is the solution that should work for you.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const alanKey = "my key";
function App() {
useEffect(() => {
   const alanBtn = require("@alan-ai/alan-sdk-web");
   alanBtn({
   key: "myKey",
   rootEl: document.getElementById("alan-btn")
  });
}, []);

return (
 <div>
  <h1>Alan AI News Application</h1>
 </div>
 );
}
export default App;
```

Here is the discussion link for the same https://github.com/alan-ai/alan-sdk-web/issues/29#issuecomment-672242925.

Hope this solves your issue.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the page is pre-rendered on the server and the navigator variable is not declared there. Before calling anything that has the navigator variable, you should check that the code is running in the browser.

```
import { platform } from 'os';

if (platform() !== 'browser') return;
console.log('This is your navigator: ', navigator);
```