# NextJS: How to correctly add firebase analytics to NextJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a react/nextjs app and I have firebase.js as follow:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/analytics'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '...'
}
try {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  firebase.analytics()
} catch (err) {
  if (!/already exists/.test(err.message)) {
    console.error('Firebase initialization error', err.stack)
  }
}

export default firebase
```

I kept getting

> Firebase initialization error ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

after adding analytics to the firebase.js file.  What is the correct way to add analytics to the app?

Comment: I have found a couple of community answers that might be related to the issue you are facing, could you try to implement those and check if it solves the issue you are facing? Here are them: [Community Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66165969/12857703), [Community Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63539271/12857703).

Comment: I tried #1, but no luck

Comment: What about #2? I believe initializing analytics inside a `useEffect()` will fix the issue.

Comment: so, when you are using firebase it is recomended use this instead of the script way ?

Answer (score 35):

```
import { getAnalytics, isSupported } from "firebase/analytics";

const analytics = isSupported().then(yes => yes ? getAnalytics(app) : null);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this one

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/firestore"
import "firebase/storage"
import "firebase/analytics"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEASUREMENT_ID,
}
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

// Auth export
export const auth = firebase.auth()

// Firestore exports
export const firestore = firebase.firestore()
export const serverTimestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp
export const fbTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp
export const fromMillis = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis
export const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment

// Storage exports
export const storage = firebase.storage()

export const analytics = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    return firebase.analytics()
  } else {
    return null
  }
}
export default firebase
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and look no further. My two cents are import analytics like this `import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";` and export it like this `export const analytics = typeof window !== "undefined" ? getAnalytics(firebase) : null;` for more modern code.

Answer (score 2):

## Using firebase V 9.16 this how I solved the issue

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics, isSupported } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};
let app; let analytics; let db
if(typeof window != undefined){
  app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  analytics = isSupported().then(yes => yes ? getAnalytics(app) : null);
  db = getFirestore(app)
}


export {app, analytics, db}
```

### In _app.js I import analytics and i use useEffect like

```
useEffect(() => {
    analytics;
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

`ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`
because there is no window object present during the server-side rendering of the Nextjs application.

Try:

```js
if(typeof window != undefined){
     firebase.analytics()
}
```

Comment: If that works for you I found an article that talks about it in some more depth. https://medium.com/wesionary-team/integration-of-firebase-analytics-in-nextjs-application-in-minutes-ea5e051ef82a

Comment: I just tried this, still getting the error.

Comment: The condition is wrong. Here is the right condition :
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {

Answer (score 1):

Using top-level await

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics, isSupported } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
  ... 
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const analytics = await isSupported() ? getAnalytics(firebaseApp) : null

export { analytics }
```

And then using logEvent from firebase/analytics

```js
import { logEvent } from "firebase/analytics";
import { analytics } from "../../firebase/init";

  useEffect(() => {

    analytics && logEvent(analytics, 'page_view', {
      page_title: "/",
      page_path: "/",
    });

  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my firebase to version 9 and this error is not seen.

Update to version 9 could be a solution to this.

But for version 9, there are some changes in firebase declaration.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'
```